# What, if anything, has replaced activex controls in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

I'm looking up how to create an activex control to add to IE and find out that activex controls are just COM objects.  So I look that up and find that COM is old and has been replaced by .NET

So I was wondering, what is the modern equivalent for activex controls in IE or is activex still the thing to use when IE is involved?

In case this takes me down a better path, I'm trying to get content from a web page into another web page to aid user productivity.  I have looked at AHK, but the specific webpage is SSL and requires two certificates, so I'm suspecting that this is stopping direct access to the url's content.

Comment: Don't down-vote without some explanation - that isn't helpful at all

Comment: By the lack of an answer to this, I am assuming that activex is what I need to use still - so that's what I will continue to pursue

Comment: *In case this takes me down a better path, I'm trying to get content from a web page into another web page to aid user productivity.* can you explain it more? Maybe you don't need to create an IE extension.

Comment: The content I am copying is not inside a textbox, it is just text on the page.  Using AHK, I can collect the contents of regular pages and parse it, but this page denies access without the certificates (which are, of course, in the browser setup), so by adding an IE extension I can get access to the content that way.  If there is another way, then I'm happy to use that.

Comment: I couldn't understand the requirement well, but maybe a `WebBrowser` control help you. You can manipulate its displaying content and and interact with it in a windows forms application.